# How to combine multiple custom hook fetches in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How would I combine multiple custom hook fetches in a component if the result of the first fetch is used by the second fetch?  I'm not sure how to do it since a custom hook can't be put in a variable.

```
  const App = () => {

  useEffect(() => {
    // first fetch
    const { isLoading, isError, data } = useDataApi(`url`, 'GET', body )
    // second fetch that uses "data" returned from the first fetch
    const { isLoading, isError, data } = useDataApi(`url/data`, 'GET', body )
  }, []);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is simple pattern to reuse fetch logic eg.

```
const useRequest = (fetchData) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null)
  const [error, setError] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData().then(setData).catch(setError)
  }, [])

  const isLoading = !data && !error
  const isError = !!error

  return {isLoading, isError, data}
}
```

And how you can use it in functional component

```
function App() {
  const {isLoading, isError, data} = useRequest(() =>
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1').then((res) =>
      res.json(),
    ),
  )

  if (isError) return <div>Error</div>
  if (isLoading) return <div>Loading...</div>

  return <div>{JSON.stringify(data)}</div>
}
```

Comment: I know about this pattern, but all of my fetches are complex and not straight forward enough to use this simple custom hook and are already written in vanilla JS, so I don't want to have to rewrite them.

Comment: Can You share with me what kind of complexity you mean? From what I see this should be enough for case in question

Comment: If you need more "complex" quering solutions you can take a look at fiew popular libraries: https://react-query.tanstack.com/ or https://swr.vercel.app/

Comment: I could possibly use this, but how would I combine calls that depend on each other.  For instance, the what the first call returns is used by the second call?  Since you can't put the custom hook in a variable, I'm confused how you'd do this.

Comment: Also, if I wanted to use this fetch when a component mounted and only then, I'd put it in a useEffect in that component?  It seems like doubling up useEffect

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-cannon-43jfc?file=/src/index.js - example of dependent queries

Comment: Thanks.  I need the fetches to be in the same component though:
`
  const App = () => {

  useEffect(() => {
    // first fetch
    const { isLoading, isError, data } = useDataApi(`url`, 'GET', body )
    // second fetch that uses "data" returned from the first fetch
    const { isLoading, isError, data } = useDataApi(`url/data`, 'GET', body )
  }, []);
  }
`

Comment: Updated question

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-cannon-43jfc?file=/src/index.js

Comment: Let me know if this is something that you need

Comment: fetchData function could be as complex as You wish. It has to return a promise tho

Comment: That is super close, what if I just wanted the fetch to be in the custom hook and not being passed to it?  So the custom fetch hook would get the URL, and the fetch would be in its useEffect.

Comment: Like in the question I rewrote.  You pass the URL instead of the fetch function.

Comment: I think that if You need custom functions to fetch something it is better to leave this as I have shown (not dependent on any internal library/fetch implementation)